# TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="provider", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.2)

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat

It seems like the syntax has changed a bit, the course I am following might have outdated syntax but I am unable to find the correct syntax to get the balance. Could someone help me, the code is this -

```
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat")
const { assert, expect } = require("chai")
describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator
    const sendValue = ethers.parseEther("1")
    beforeEach(async function () {
        // const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        // const accountZero = accounts[0]
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        fundMe = await ethers.getContract("FundMe", deployer)
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract(
            "MockV3Aggregator",
            deployer
        )
    })
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed()
            assert.equal(response, await mockV3Aggregator.getAddress())
        })
    })

    describe("fund", async function () {
        it("Fails if you dont send enough ETH", async function () {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more ETH!"
            )
        })
        it("amount funded", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const response = await fundMe.getAddressToAmountFunded(deployer)
            assert.equal(response.toString(), sendValue.toString())
        })
        it("Adds funder to array of funders", async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
            const funder = await fundMe.getFunder(0)
            assert.equal(funder, deployer)
        })
    })

    describe("withdraw", async function () {
        beforeEach(async function () {
            await fundMe.fund({ value: sendValue })
        })

        it("withdraw ETH from a single founder", async function () {
            //Arrange
            const startingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.address
            )
            const startingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer
            )
            //Act
            const transactionResponse = await fundMe.withdraw()
            const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
            const {gasUsed, effectiveGasPrice} = transactionReceipt
            const gasCost = gasUsed.mul(effectiveGasPrice)

            const endingFundMeBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                fundMe.address
            )
            const endingDeployerBalance = await fundMe.provider.getBalance(
                deployer
            )
            //gasCost
            //Assert
            assert.equal(endingFundMeBalance, 0)
            assert.equal(
                startingFundMeBalance.add(startingDeployerBalance),
                endingDeployerBalance.add(gasCost).toString()
            )
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I believe there is a dependency conflict, I am in the same situation as you

Answer (score 0):

I posted a help here, maybe it concerns you too because there are dependencies conflicts with this course.

https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/issues/170#issuecomment-1625139769

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. After several tries, I found it work with replacing fundme by ethers:

```
const startingMyFundMeBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
            await myFundMe.getAddress());
```